# How can I expand a container iside a column in flutter without overflowing?

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow

I'm trying to expand a container inside of a column, but when I try to use the expanded widget, it overflows the screen. How can I expand the middle container without overflowing the screen?

```
Column(
          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.,
          // padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          // shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            _PlayingGameAppBar(
              onZero: () => zerar(),
              time: time,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    // height: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 8, bottom: 8, left: 4, right: 4),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          widget.theme.name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black45,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 7),
                  Container( /// I want to expand this container, to make it fill the avaiable space
                    // constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 100),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(Size.fromHeight(100)),
                    // height: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: answers.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        ThemeAnswer answer = answers[index];
                        return Center(
                          child: AnswerTile(
                            answer: answer.answer,
                            points: answer.points,
                            direction: AnswerDirection.left,
                            alignment: AnswerTileAlignment.LEFT,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _answerController,
                        onChanged: (text) =>
                            setState(() => this.text = text),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: loc.answerInputHint,
                          suffixIcon: Opacity(
                            opacity: text.isEmpty ? 0.4 : 1,
                            child: AbsorbPointer(
                              absorbing: text.isEmpty,
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
                                onPressed: () => onSend,
                                tooltip: loc.add,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I have tried to expand with the Expanded widget, Flexible widget, IntrinsicHeight widget and defining with MediaQuery, but it did not expand

Comment: Column aligns its children vertically and it does not have any limit on the size perspective. It will just lay out children as they are. If you try to use something that expands to available vertical space (a Container widget wrapped in Expanded for example) as a child, there will be an error. What kind of information are you planning to hold in that Container? Have you tried giving it a certain size? You can use MediaQuery.of(context).size to achieve responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your `Column` scrollable due to the `Container` expansion, try wrapping your `Column` into a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

If you want yo make your `Container` scrollable when expanded, try instead this:

- wrap your `Container` into a `SingleChildScrollView`
- wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` into an `Expanded`: this will force the container to fill the remaining space and will impose some constraints (`Column` does not impose height constraints, this is why you need it.)

Either way this should do the trick!